Uploading data to mysql database "Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field"
I am trying to upload some geospatial data to a mysql database using geopandas.to_sql. When I try to do that in some instances I get the following error:
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1416, 'Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field')
[SQL: INSERT INTO tbl_nuts_regions (`nuts_ID`, nuts_level, name, country_numeric, wkb) VALUES (%(nuts_ID)s, %(nuts_level)s, %(name)s, %(country_numeric)s, %(wkb)s)]
[parameters: {'nuts_ID': 'NO05', 'nuts_level': 2, 'name': 'Vestlandet', 'country_numeric': 578, 'wkb': b'\x01\x06\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\xcf\x07\x00\x00\x80:u\x9e\xde\x80 @\xd0V\xd3\xffv\x89N@\xc0Bw\xe1\xb8\x90 @ ... (108942 characters truncated) ... c6\x13@(Fd\xff\x0c\x91N@\x80S\\\x80v\xca\x13@\xb8\xd2k N\x90N@@\xdc\xcf\\\xb9\xd0\x13@8\x9c\xbc\xdf \x90N@@\xacU\x02\xfc\xd1\x13@\x88\x91{\xe0A\x90N@'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

Using chunksize=1 I realized that this error does not occur in all instances. However I don´t know why this happens in that particular instance (it´s the 9th instance). I tried plotting the data and it works just fine so it does not seem to be due to corrupted data. My guess is that the geometry (MULITPOLYGON) is just very big and that causes the issue. But I could not find a way to fix this. The data I am trying to upload to the database can be found here: https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/statistical-units/territorial-units-statistics (using NUTS 2003, SHP, Polygons (RG), 20M, EPSG: 4326). And this is my code:
import geopandas as gpd 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
nuts_2003 = gpd.read(r'FILEPATH', encoding='ISO-8859-1') 
engine = create_engine('...') 
nuts_2003['wkb'] = nuts_2003['geometry'].to_wkb(hex=False) 
nuts_2003 = nuts_2003.drop(columns=['CNTR_CODE', 'geometry']) 
nuts_data.to_sql('tbl_nuts_regions', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)  

The exception is thrown in the last row within the to_sql function.
Package versions: geopandas 1.0.1; sqlalchemy 2.0.35; python 3.12.6
